# How to disable user from entering same input in text box?

Tags: c#, variables, textbox

i knew i made something wrong because its still can accept same input from textbox. Can someone help me with this silly trick.

```
private void btnSpot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string animal=txtAnimal.Text;

    if (i <= 3)
    {
        string insertedAnimal = "";

        if (insertedAnimal!=txtAnimal.Text)
        {              
            if (animal == "Cheetah" || animal == "Giraffe")
            {
                lboDisp.Items.Add("Animal " + i + ": " + animal + ".");
                lboDisp.Items.Add(" A " + animal + " has spots.");
                lboDisp.Items.Add("");
                j++;
            }

            else
            {
                lboDisp.Items.Add("Animal " + i + ": " + animal + ".");
                lboDisp.Items.Add("I don't think that a " + animal + " has spots.");
                lboDisp.Items.Add("");
            }

            lblResult.Text = j + " of animals you have entered have spots.";
            i++;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You've entered the same animal");
        }
        insertedAnimal = txtAnimal.Text;        
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Press Reset button to restart program");
    }     
}
```

Comment: is this WPF or winforms?

Comment: you can check `if(!lboDisp.Contains(txtAnimal.Text))`, it will check all values that `lboDisp` contains

Comment: He can't do it this way because inside lboDisp he's building some text which never be equal to input text. Of course he can iterate over listbox items, check if item contains input text but that sounds like an overkill. Better idea would be to create enteredAnimalsList, insert every input there and check if it contains.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is this line:

```
 string insertedAnimal = "";
```

If the user has entered an animal in txtAnimal, it will always be different.  You need to set insertedAnimal to equal the user's previous input.

Comment: You're right in figuring out the problem, but I don't think that's the solution. `insertedAnimal` should be set to the user's previously entered input, not the current user input. And for that to work, the previously entered input should be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the line

```
string insertedAnimal = "";
```

outside of the method, as a local variable:

```
class SomeClass // Whatever the name of your class is
{
    private string insertedAnimal = "";
    private void btnSpot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

This way, it will only be set to `""` when creating the form, not every time the button is pressed, when you actually want to have the old value to compare to.